# How to set the title attribute of input via css only

Tags: html, css

I want to set the title of my textbox using css. It is possible via jquery but I want to set it via css.

Comment: If CSS were to be used to set attributes, then what is the role of HTML markup?

Comment: Any reason why you need to do this?

Comment: css can't change values of attributes. Plain js is enough for this task (jQuery not strictly necessary)

Comment: I want to add title to class that is added to element at runtime.

Comment: you don't add title to class. you add that to element.

Comment: @Fabrizio I dont want to change the existing value. I want to bind the static text with that class

Comment: @KulbirSingh a fiddle with a description would help a lot

Comment: I have class 'textClass' that is given to textbox. I want to bind the title to 'myClass' via css

Comment: do you mean you want to apply myClass to all textboxes with a specific title?

Comment: No no, i dont want to select the element via title selector. I want to set the value of title attribute(custom texts)

Comment: I am confused why my question is declared duplicated the question that they suggested and said here is answer is totally different answer. I have said in my question that I want to do through css but suggested question's answer is done through jquery

Comment: @KulbirSingh: did you see Quentin's comment above?

Comment: @Abhitalks for your comment  "you don't add title to class. you add that to element", you are programmer bro, Its common sense I know title will be added to element but initially my element have no class, I am adding classes to my element at runtime, So thats why I used that term that means I want to add title ti my element accroding to class added at runtime

Comment: @KulbirSingh: Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Abhitalks bro thanks for sharing. but nothing was confusing in my question, as a developer everyone knows class would be applied to element and I am asking to apply title attribute to class (I used class term because class is applied at runtime)

Answer (score 2):

CSS has been designed for the design aspect of a website, not for the content of it. There exists a property called content though. Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/css-content/.

EDIT: With this you are only capable of adding Textnodes, not adding or changing attributes of any other nodes.